# How to make fixed left column when i scroll in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fullcalendar

[image]

Hi, am using jQuery fullcalendar for my website.i can scroll horizontally,but i need to make my left column which is having time as fixed.how to make it has fixed in full calendar ?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: You are solved it